# Skipping Sendmail's Queue

Tags: linux, sendmail

I've set up Sendmail so that all messages are delivered to /dev/null instead of being actually stored anywhere else. I'm trying to reduce the number of unecessary disk writes and since those messages are essentially removed I want to, if possible, skip writing them to mqueue. Is there any way to do that?

The closest I could think of is mounting a nullfs filesystem on the mqueue directory, but I'd like a "cleaner" approach using sendmail only. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I can't imagine why you're sending mail to `/dev/null` but if you need to test functionality of sending-mail without actually bothering people, I've had very good success using Docker and an off-the-shelf image called "Mailhog" which is exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Diego, this is also an "XY Question."  You want Y, and you assume that X is the way to get Y so you ask about X and not Y.  You never actually tell us what your *underlying objective* is, nor what's keeping you from getting there – that is to say, "Y."  We could probably help you with "Y."  But not if you only (vaguely ...) talk about "X."  Please read the various SO writeups on how to pose a good, *actionable* question.

Comment: Basically what I need is to accept mail for any user in any @domain that arrives at the server and discard those messages. Business requirements say that we can't bounce any mail messages that arrive to any domain hosted at the server, and instead they should be discarded. Also there are no valid users in any of those domains, and no outgoing messages should be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you choose wrong way to solve your problem but anyway:

You can select `discard` mailer for all recipients in `check_rcpt` (Local_check_rcpt) rule set.  It will act as equivalent of `DISCARD` in access table.

Add the following lines to `sendmil.mc` file, generate new `sendmail.cf` file and restart or HUP sendmail daemon.

```
LOCAL_RULESETS
SLocal_check_rcpt
# PUT TAB (\t) BEFORE $# !!!
R$*    $#discard $: discard
```